# shuffle values in an integer column so they are always unique and sequential

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table I'd like to sort with a "priority" column. This column needs to be reordered when the priority of a record is changed or records are removed. Think of it as an array. The values will be modified in a UI so I want them to remain whole numbers and represent the true position within the larger recordset. The priority column won't have NULLs.

```
id       priority
1        2
2        1
3        4
4        3
```

Now say I change the priority of id 4 to 2 or I insert or delete a row how do I get all priorities to reshuffle so there are no gaps or duplicates and the highest possible priority is always the number of rows?

The table has a "date_modified" field which is accurate to the second and updated on insert/update so if needed it is possible to know which record was modified last (to break a tie when 2 records have the same priority)

Comment: a [set][1] by definition is unordered. if you want them to appear in certain order you must do something like 'ORDER BY' (which is of course used in the answers)

[1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(computer_science)

Comment: what are you on about? who ever said this was a set?

Comment: or more to the point, when did I say I wasn't going to ORDER them? What I need is a key to order them on that doesn't get fragmented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have 8.4 you can use window functions.

```
UPDATE test_priority 
SET priority = sub.new_priority
FROM (
    SELECT user_id, id, priority, rank() OVER (ORDER BY priority, date_modified) new_priority
    FROM test_priority
    WHERE user_id = $1
) sub 
WHERE test_priority.user_id = sub.user_id 
  AND test_priority.id = sub.id
  AND test_priority.priority <> sub.new_priority
```

Comment: that's more like it, I knew about rank() and I do have 8.4 but I couldn't make sense of how to use it in an UPDATE and gave up.

Comment: works a charm. it's times like this I wish you could add bounty to an answered question. i especially like that last little optimisation on the end... sure there's only 100 rows in this table and the updates are about once a day but hey, why update something if you don't have to?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a row:

```
UPDATE tbl SET priority = priority - 1 
WHERE priority > the_priority_of_what_you_deleted
```

Inserting a row (do this *before* the insert):

```
UPDATE tbl SET priority = priority + 1 
WHERE priority >= the_priority_about_to_be_inserted
```

You can put this kind of logic into `INSERT` and/or `DELETE` triggers, if you want.

Comment: but these solutions won't help if I just change the priority of an existing row - there will be a gap. Also if I delete several rows at once or manually delete rows from pgadmin. I was hoping for something a bit more generic that could be run after a sequence of changes to "smooth" out the remaining values. The triggers might do the job but they make me nervous because I don't know how they will interact with my automated backup/restore system.